# Проблема с рисованием на PictureBox (VisualStudio C++)

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Подскажите пожалуйста! Я рисую на **PictureBox** через **System::Drawing::Graphics** на странице **Page1** объекта **TabControl**.

```
 System::Drawing::Graphics ^ g;
 g = PictureBox1->CreateGraphics();
 код рисования;
```

И все хорошо, но после перехода на страницу **Page2** и возврата опять на **Page1** рисунок пропадает, т.е. пустой PictureBox.

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы рисунок оставался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно перегрузить метод [OnPaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) элемента [TabPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx), где рисуется рисунок. Рисунок рисовать в `OnPaint`, этот метод вызывается по событию `Paint` - при перерисовке элемента управления.

Comment: Попробывал просто вставить код в собитие Paint - результат тотже. А как перегрузить OnPaint, я имею ввиду как описать сам заголовок?

Comment: Не совсем вас понял, но похоже вы не то делаете. Сделайте точку останова на этой функции, она вызывается?  
В ручную лучше не делайте, сложновато. Студия сама для вас все сделает. Выделите в конструкторе формы нужный `TabPage`, в контекстном меню Свойства, там есть доступные события, находите `Paint` и делаете двойной клик, потом студия сама сгенерит нужный код, вам нужно будет только тело функции написать.

Comment: Это я вас неверное не так понял, я подумал нужно явно описать где-то перегруженное событие OnPaint.  То что можно щелкнуть на событии и студия сама все напишет в файле .h заголовок функции соответствующей событию я знаю. Только вот в чем загвоздка у TabControl события Paint нет, у когда открываешь коллекцию страниц то у страницы можно менять только свойства, событий вобще нет. Поэтому событие Paint я устанавливал у самого PictureBox, проверил дебагером оно срабытывает, рисует, но только потом все равно все сбрасывется, собственно поэтому я и задал вопрос.

Comment: У `TabControl` нету события `Paint`. Нужно в событии того элемента **TabPage**, где должен быть рисунок. Смысл события `Paint` вам понятен?  
Где у вас, на каком контроле рисунок стирается? Рисунок должен рисоваться, когда этот контрол перерисовывается, т.е. при наступлении события `Paint` этого контрола. А при наступлении события вызывается метод `OnPaint`, который вам нужно перегрузить.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!